# NodaTime get Country Time based on CountryCode

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, utc, nodatime

I've a requirement where Admin will select some `countries List` and `Time for Alert` for users for that Countries List.

Lets Say the Admin selects `24/07/2014 09:00 AM` in the Countries `India,Malaysia and Canada`,
They need to get the Alerts based on `their TimeZone` and every country user need to get the Alert at the `User's Local 9 AM Time`.

So,I only have their `country Codes` like **IN,MY,CA**

So,I thought of getting their TimeZones and calculating based on the `Server Time`.

For Example : My Server is Located in `Canada`.So,I thought of calculating the `Time to Alert` in `India` based on the `India TimeZone` and `save the Time in Db`.So my windows service will run at that India Time and push the Alert.

But for this,I need to save multiple records with different times in Db.

So,For getting the `TimeZone` based on the CountryCode, I've used **NodaTime**

```
var CountryInfo = (from location in TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
                     where location.CountryCode.Equals(CountryCode,
                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                     select new { location.ZoneId, location.CountryName })
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm getting the `TimeZoneID` from this Query.
Can we get the `CurrentDate and Time` of the `CountryCode` based on the `Admin's Selected DateTime`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is nearly correct - although it can be simplified somewhat, and made more testable, and it should handle the case where there's no such zone...

```
// You should use dependency injection really - that makes the code much more
// testable. Basically, you want an IClock...
IClock clock = SystemClock.Instance;

var countryCode = "IN";
var location = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
                 .FirstOrDefault(l => l.CountryCode == countryCode);
if (location == null)
{
    // This is up to you - there's no location with your desired country code.
}
else
{
    var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[location.ZoneId];
    var zonedNow = clock.Now.InZone(zone);
    // Now do what you want with zonedNow... I'd avoid going back into BCL
    // types, myself.
}
```

Bear in mind that this assumes there's just *one* time zone for a country - that's not always the case. Think of the US, where there are *lot* of time zones...

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion @Jon Skeet
As,I've observed the SystemClock.Instance is giving out UtcNow right?
can you also look into my requirement and give me any suggestions.
Because I feel that I'm doing in the wrong way to save multiple records for the countries and sending through windows service.

Comment: @RealSteel: Well, `IClock.Now` returns an `Instant`, which isn't in any particular time zone (or calendar). But fundamentally, if you only know someone's country, you can't tell their time zone necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

I got the Date by using this :

```
string CountryCode = "IN";

                var CountryInfo = (from location in TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
                                   where location.CountryCode.Equals(CountryCode,
                                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                   select new { location.ZoneId, location.CountryName })
                 .FirstOrDefault();

                var TimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[CountryInfo.ZoneId];
                DateTime objdate = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow)
                          .InZone(TimeZone)
                          .ToDateTimeUnspecified();
```